# Accessing env variables set through robot framework in jenkins editable email notification

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I am running a robot framework test case through Jenkins (with parameters, and in my test case, I set some environment variables. I would like to use these variables in my editable email template.

I have tried doing different formats of including these environment variables, such as:

```
env.VARAIBLE
${VARIABLE}
$VARIABLE
%VARIABLE%
```

But they are always just printing the way I wrote them, instead of with the actual value

Jenkins execute windows batch command:

```
cd Tests
Robot -d ../Reports --variable USERNAME:%USERNAME% --variable 
PASSWORD:%PASSWORD% AutomationTest.robot
```

Robot AutomationTest.robot code:

```
Automation Test
        ${data} =   convert to string   Hello world                 
        Set Environment Variable    VARIABLE       ${data}
```

Email template segment:

```
<h3>
$JOB_BASE_NAME build for the user env.USERNAME, result = env.VARIABLE
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot set an environment variable in a robot test and expect that variable to be visible outside of the test. That is not how environment variables work -- a child process can't set variables in its parent process.

I don't know how you're using the email template, but if it's part of the jenkins configuration rather than a template loaded into the robot test, there's no way for it to see the environment variable.

Comment: Alright, good to know. I suppose I'll go in the direction where I inject them into an xml file that is built in the test, and attach that to the email.